Zip without preserve permissions
I'm trying to pack files into zip archive without preserving their original permissions. When i do it in Windows (by system util or with 7zip) it doesn't save this info. But when i archive same folder from Ubuntu 22.04 I'm getting new property for each file and directory, that stores original permissions. I can see it in Ark - there are 2 archives on screenshot, top one zipped on Windows and bottom on Ubuntu - comparing 2 archives in Ark
I need it because my colleagues had some problems with permissions after unpacking my archive, that weren't with windows-packed ones.
So I tried to use flag -X for zip command like
zip -X testZip.zip ./index.html 

but permissions still there.
Didn't found any commands to clean them from zipped folder, may be need to use another compress tool, but don't know which one

Since 7-Zip satisfies your requirements in Windows, try using it in Ubuntu.
Under wine, 7-Zip works very well in Linux, and is my preferred archive utility. There are a few ways to do this:

Download the 7-Zip executable installer and use wine to run it.
Download the 7-Zip executable installer and use a Zip utility to open that executable, then copy that to a folder in your /home directory, such as /home/vosk/winapps/7-zip/. Then create a shortcut to wine /home/vosk/winapps/7-zip/7zFM.exe to run the utility.
If you have already installed 7-Zip on Windows for a dual-boot machine, then simply point wine to the mounted NTFS location with 7-Zip -- not installation needed.

BTW, first time an application is run in wine it may take a minute or two for wine to create a local environment, but subsequently, the app should start about as quickly as a native Linux app (and faster then Ubuntu Snap apps).
Why not use p7Zip, a port of 7-Zip? It has not been updated for a number of years, apparently, and is far behind the current version of 7-Zip.
